# Калькулятор расчёта стоимости

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, form

Есть два ползунка, Количество звонков и средняя продолжительность звонка. Есть итоговая стоимость звонка. Значения ползунков находятся в input value. Базовая стоимость 200. Суть такова, если значение первого ползунка больше 3х то к цене прибавляется допустим + 150, также если значение второго ползунка тоже больше 3х то к стоимости прибавляется допустим + 130. Итого если у обоих ползунков значение >=3 200+130+150 = 480. И если значение выше 7 то к этой цифре ещё добавляется допустим + 200. Значение value их input я уже получил, но как обработать такой функционал и передать его в input value общей стоимости - я не знаю. Подскажите с реализацией, пожалуйста. 
(Ползунок noUiSlider, подгрузить его не получилось сюда, поэтому value для input прописал вручную).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С вашей библиотекой.

```js
const startPrice = 200;
const firstInputStep = new Array( ['>=3', 150], ['>=7', 350] );
const secondInputStep = new Array( ['>=3', 200], ['>=7', 400] );

let firstSlider;
let secondSlider;
const price = document.getElementById('price');

init();
addListeners();
calculatePrice();

function init () {
  firstSlider = noUiSlider.create(document.getElementById('first-slider'), {
    start: [2],
    connect: true,
    tooltips: [true],
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 50
    }
  });
  secondSlider = noUiSlider.create(document.getElementById('second-slider'), {
    start: [2],
    connect: true,
    tooltips: [true],
    step: 1,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 50
    }
  });
}

function addListeners () {
  firstSlider.on('slide', calculatePrice);
  secondSlider.on('slide', calculatePrice);
}

function calculatePrice () {
  let firstValue = firstSlider.get();
  let secondValue = secondSlider.get();
  let finallyPrice = (typeof startPrice === 'number') ? startPrice : 0;
  finallyPrice += getStepByValue(firstInputStep, firstValue);
  finallyPrice += getStepByValue(secondInputStep, secondValue);
  price.innerText = `price: ${finallyPrice}`;
}

function getStepByValue (stepsMap, val) {
  let stepPrice = 0;
  val = Number.parseInt(val);
  if (typeof val === 'number') {
      for (let item of stepsMap) {
          if (eval(`${val}${item[0]}`)) {
              stepPrice = item[1];
          }
      }
  }
  return stepPrice;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.5.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/14.5.0/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div style="padding: 15px">
  <p>Slider 1:</p>
  <div id="first-slider"></div>
  <p>Slider 2:</p>
  <div id="second-slider"></div>
  <p>Price: </p>
  <div id="price"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё супер пока что, как сделать так чтобы инпут был type="hidden". Поскольку в него предаётся только значение и он скрыт, с type number всё работает, а вот с hidden к сожалению нет. Дело в том что в type number не передаётся значение value от nuUiSlider, а в hidden - передаётся. Подскажи как исправить. В целом реализация супер!
Upd: я ещё вижу что значение с type number передаётся в value, но самого value в input нет, а число меняется, но число как будто призрачное, оно не считается.

Comment: Более правильное решение - повесить обработчик на ваш слайдер.
[события вашей библиотеки](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/).

И в функции `calculatePrice` [получать значения библиотеки](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/).

Comment: На данный момент событие change передаёт значение из ползунка в input value. А уже с него по Вашему коду мы берём данные, как реализовать в коде уже прямой экспорт в калькулятор?

Comment: Изменил ответ. Не нужно усложнять жизнь лишними `input`.

Comment: а как сделать так чтобы значения между собой перемножались? Допустим second = 2 , а first = 10, = 20. То есть значения между ними перемножались.